# 'Tensor Calculus' by J.L. Synge and A. Schild (1979 Dover publication) . Exercise 12 page 110.

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-analysis, tensors

I'm solving all the exercises  of 'Tensor Calculus' by J.L. Synge and A. Schild (1979 Dover publication) . Till now everything went smooth, but now I'm stuck at exercise 12. page 110 of the third chapter on 'Curvature'.
The exercise is stated as

Prove that the quantities $$G^{mn}+ \frac{1}{2a}\frac{\delta^2}{\delta x^x \delta x^s}\left[ a \left( a^{mn}a^{rs}-a^{mr}a^{ns} \right)\right]$$ can be expressed in terms of the metric tensor and its first derivatives.

First, there must  be a typo error as $\delta x^x $ in $\frac{\delta^2}{\delta x^x \delta x^s}$ makes no sense. So I guess this must be  $\frac{\delta^2}{\delta x^r \delta x^s}$. Secondly, and that is my first question, it seems odd to me that the authors use  the absolute derivative symbol  in this expression. That does not make sense to me and I suppose they mean the covariant derivative instead. So the expression (sorry, I use the notational convention of the book and not the more modern one with $\nabla$ or $;$) should be $G^{mn}+ \frac{1}{2a}\left[ a \left( a^{mn}a^{rs}-a^{mr}a^{ns} \right)\right]_{|rs}$. Am I right?

Second question. Does someone know why the author chose this expression? Is it used somewhere in general relativity or physics in general? The pattern in the second term suggest remotely a connection with the Riemannian curvature ...

Third question, does any one know the best approach to tackle the exercise? I made a lot of attempts but always get  stuck. Probably I got blind sighted and I'm turning around in the same wrong logic...

For those interested, here's my best shot, which leads to ... nothing

$$\blacklozenge$$

Let's define
\begin{align}
K^{mn} &\equiv \frac{1}{2a}\frac{\delta^2}{\delta x^r \delta x^s}\left[ a \left( a^{mn}a^{rs}-a^{mr}a^{ns} \right)\right]\\
T^{mn} &\equiv G^{mn}+ K^{mn}
\end{align}
The strategy to proof this, is to separate in both terms of the expression, the parts that can be expressed in $a_{ij}, a^{ij}, \partial_k a_{ij}, \partial_k a^{ij}$ and the parts of higher order differentiation.
We begin with the second term.

As the covariant derivatives of the metric tensor vanish, we get
\begin{align}
K^{mn} &=\frac{1}{2a}\left[ a \left( a^{mn}a^{rs}-a^{mr}a^{ns} \right)\right] _{|rs}\\
&= \frac{1}{2a}\left[ a_{|r} \left( a^{mn}a^{rs}-a^{mr}a^{ns} \right)+ a \underbrace{\left( a^{mn}a^{rs}-a^{mr}a^{ns} \right)_{|r}}_{=0}\right] _{|s}\\
&= \frac{1}{2a}\left[ a_{|r} \left( a^{mn}a^{rs}-a^{mr}a^{ns} \right)\right] _{|s}\\
&= \frac{1}{2a}\left[ \underbrace{a_{|rs}}_{=\partial^2_{rs} a} \left( a^{mn}a^{rs}-a^{mr}a^{ns} \right)+a_{|r} \underbrace{\left( a^{mn}a^{rs}-a^{mr}a^{ns} \right)_{|s}}_{=0} \right]
\end{align}
Considering,
\begin{align}
\partial^2_{rs} \ln a&= \partial_s \left(\frac{1}{a}\partial_r a\right)\\
&= \frac{1}{a}\partial^2_{rs}a-\frac{1}{a^2}\partial_r a\partial_s a\\
\Rightarrow\quad \frac{1}{a}\partial^2_{rs}a &= \partial^2_{rs} \ln a+ \frac{1}{a^2}\partial_r a\partial_s a
\end{align}
\begin{align}
\Rightarrow \quad K^{mn} &= \frac{1}{2}\left( a^{mn}a^{rs}-a^{mr}a^{ns} \right)\partial^2_{rs}\ln a+\mathcal{E}^{mn} 
\end{align}
with $\mathcal{E}^{mn}$ being a function in  $a_{ij}, a^{ij}, \partial_k a_{ij}, \partial_k a^{ij}$ only.

Note that $\mathcal{E}^{mn}$ is a symmetrical object in $m,n$. Indeed,
\begin{align}
\mathcal{E}^{mn} &= \frac{1}{2a^2}\left( a^{mn}a^{rs}-a^{mr}a^{ns} \right)\partial_r a\partial_s a\\
\Rightarrow\quad \mathcal{E}^{nm} &= \frac{1}{2a^2}\left( a^{nm}a^{rs}-a^{nr}a^{ms} \right)\partial_r a\partial_s a\\
&= \frac{1}{2a^2}\left( a^{mn}a^{sr}-a^{ns}a^{mr} \right)\partial_s a\partial_r a\\
&= \mathcal{E}^{mn}
\end{align}

We now rewrite $G^{mn}$.

We have:
\begin{align}
G^{mn} &= a^{nk}G^m_{. \ k}\\
G^m_{. \ k} &= R^m_{. \ k}-\frac{1}{2}\delta^m_k R\\
R^m_{. \ k} &= a^{mp} R_{pk}\\
R &= a^{pk}R_{pk}
\end{align}
And by $3.205.$
\begin{align}
R_{pk} = \frac{1}{2} \partial^2_{pk} \ln a -  \partial_t \Gamma^t_{pk} + \mathcal{F}^{pk}
\end{align}
With $\mathcal{F}^{pk}$ a function in  $a_{ij}, a^{ij}, \partial_k a_{ij}, \partial_k a^{ij}$ only. Note that $\mathcal{F}^{pk}$ is a symmetrical object in $p,k$ as $R_{pk}$ is a symmetrical tensor in $p,k$.
Hence by $(15)$ to $(19)$:
\begin{align}
G^{mn} &= a^{nk} R^m_{. \ k}-\frac{1}{2} a^{nk}\delta^m_k R \\
&=  a^{nk} a^{mp} R_{pk}-\frac{1}{2} a^{nm}a^{pk}R_{pk} \\
&=  \left( a^{nk} a^{mp} -\frac{1}{2} a^{nm}a^{pk}\right)R_{pk} \\
&=  \left( a^{nk} a^{mp} -\frac{1}{2} a^{nm}a^{pk}\right)\left(\frac{1}{2} \partial^2_{pk} \ln a -  \partial_t \Gamma^t_{pk} + \mathcal{F}^{pk}\right) \\
&=  \left( a^{nk} a^{mp} -\frac{1}{2} a^{nm}a^{pk}\right)\left(\frac{1}{2} \partial^2_{pk} \ln a -  \partial_t \Gamma^t_{pk} \right)+ \mathcal{H}^{mn}\\
&= \left[ \frac{1}{2} a^{nk}a^{mp}\partial^2_{pk} \ln a -  a^{nk}a^{mp}\partial_t \Gamma^t_{pk} -\frac{1}{4} a^{nm} a^{pk} \partial^2_{pk} \ln a +\frac{1}{2} a^{nm} a^{pk}  \partial_t \Gamma^t_{pk} \right]+ \mathcal{H}^{mn}
\end{align}
with $\mathcal{H}^{mn}$ a function in  $a_{ij}, a^{ij}, \partial_k a_{ij}, \partial_k a^{ij}$ only.

Note that $\mathcal{H}^{mn}$ is a symmetrical object in $m,n$ . Indeed,
\begin{align}
\mathcal{H}^{mn} &= \left( a^{nk} a^{mp} -\frac{1}{2} a^{nm}a^{pk}\right)\mathcal{F}^{pk}\\
\Rightarrow\quad \mathcal{H}^{nm} &= \left( a^{mk} a^{np} -\frac{1}{2} a^{mn}a^{pk}\right)\mathcal{F}^{pk}\\
&= \left( a^{mp} a^{nk} -\frac{1}{2} a^{mn}a^{kp}\right)\mathcal{F}^{kp}\\
&= \mathcal{H}^{mn}
\end{align}

Putting  $(10)$ and $(2)$ together with $\mathcal{L}^{mn}=\mathcal{E}^{mn}+ \mathcal{H}^{mn}$ we get,
\begin{align}
T^{mn} &= Q^{mn}+\mathcal{L}^{mn}
\end{align}
with $\mathcal{L}^{mn}$ a symmetrical object in $m,n$ and depending only on terms in $a_{ij}, a^{ij}, \partial_k a_{ij}, \partial_k a^{ij}$  and
\begin{align}
 Q^{mn} &\equiv \left\{ \begin{array}{l}
\frac{1}{2} a^{nr}a^{ms}\partial^2_{rs} \ln a -  a^{nr}a^{ms}\partial_t \Gamma^t_{rs}\\\\ -\frac{1}{4} a^{nm} a^{rs} \partial^2_{rs} \ln a
+\frac{1}{2} a^{nm} a^{rs}  \partial_t \Gamma^t_{rs}\\\\+\frac{1}{2} a^{mn}a^{rs}\partial^2_{rs}\ln a-\frac{1}{2} a^{mr}a^{ns} \partial^2_{rs}\ln a\\\\
\end{array} \right. \\
&= \frac{1}{4} a^{mn}a^{rs}\partial^2_{rs}\ln a + \left( \frac{1}{2} a^{mn}a^{rs}- a^{ms}a^{nr}\right)\partial_t \Gamma^t_{rs}
\end{align}
Note that
\begin{align}
 Q^{nm} &= \frac{1}{4} a^{nm}a^{rs}\partial^2_{rs}\ln a + \left( \frac{1}{2} a^{nm}a^{rs}- a^{ns}a^{mr}\right)\partial_t \Gamma^t_{rs} \\
&= \frac{1}{4} a^{mn}a^{rs}\partial^2_{rs}\ln a + \left( \frac{1}{2} a^{mn}a^{rs}- a^{nr}a^{ms}\right)\partial_t \Gamma^t_{sr} \\
&= Q^{mn} 
\end{align}
So $Q^{mn} $ is a symmetrical object in $m,n$

Given that by $(2.541.)$,
\begin{align}
\partial^2_{rs} \ln a &= \partial_{s} \partial_r \ln a \\
&= \partial_{s} \left(a^{kt}\partial_r a_{kt}\right)\\
&= \partial_{s} a^{kt}\partial_{r} a_{kt}+a^{kt}\partial^2_{rs} a_{kt} 
\end{align}

$(32)$ can be written as

\begin{align}
Q^{mn} &= \mathcal{P}^{mn}+ \mathcal{Z}^{mn}
\end{align}
with $\mathcal{Z}^{mn} = \frac{1}{4} a^{mn}a^{rs}\partial_{s} a^{kt}\partial_{r} a_{kt}$ a symmetric object in $m,n$ and depending only on terms in $a_{ij}, a^{ij}, \partial_k a_{ij}, \partial_k a^{ij}$

and
\begin{align}
\mathcal{P}^{mn} = \frac{1}{4} a^{mn}a^{rs}a^{kt}\partial^2_{rs} a_{kt} + \left( \frac{1}{2} a^{mn}a^{rs}- a^{ms}a^{nr}\right)\partial_t \Gamma^t_{rs}
\end{align}
Expanding the Christoffel symbols and playing with the dummy indices, gives
\begin{align}
\mathcal{P}^{mn} &= \left\{\begin{array}{l}\frac{1}{4} a^{mn}a^{rs}a^{kt}\partial^2_{rs} a_{kt} \\\\
+ \left( \frac{1}{2} a^{mn}a^{rs}- a^{ms}a^{nr}\right)\left( [rs,k]\partial_t a^{tk}+ a^{kt}\partial_t[rs,k]\right)
\end{array}\right.\\
&= \frac{1}{2} \mathcal{V}^{mn}  +\mathcal{A}^{mn}
\end{align}
with
\begin{align}
\mathcal{A}^{mn} &= \left( \frac{1}{2} a^{mn}a^{rs}- a^{ms}a^{nr}\right) [rs,k]\partial_t a^{tk}
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{2} \mathcal{V}_{mn} &= \left\{\begin{array}{l}
\frac{1}{4} a^{mn}a^{rs}a^{kt}\partial^2_{rs} a_{kt} \\\\
+ \left( \frac{1}{4} a^{mn}a^{rs} a^{kt}- \frac{1}{2} a^{ms}a^{nr} a^{kt}\right)\left( \partial^2_{tr}a_{sk}+\partial^2_{ts}a_{rk}-\partial^2_{tk}a_{rs}\right)
\end{array}\right.\\
&= \left\{\begin{array}{l}
\underline{\frac{1}{4} a^{mn}a^{rs}a^{kt}\partial^2_{rs} a_{kt} }
+ \underbrace{\frac{1}{4} a^{mn}a^{rs} a^{kt} \partial^2_{tr}a_{sk}+ \frac{1}{4} a^{mn}a^{rs} a^{kt} \partial^2_{ts}a_{rk}}_{= \frac{1}{2} a^{mn}a^{rs} a^{kt} \partial^2_{tr}a_{sk}}
- \underline{\frac{1}{4} a^{mn}a^{rs} a^{kt} \partial^2_{tk}a_{rs}}\\\\
- \frac{1}{2} a^{ms}a^{nr} a^{kt} \partial^2_{tr}a_{sk}
- \frac{1}{2} a^{ms}a^{nr} a^{kt} \partial^2_{ts}a_{rk}
+ \frac{1}{2} a^{ms}a^{nr} a^{kt} \partial^2_{tk}a_{rs}\\
\end{array}\right.
\end{align}
giving
\begin{align}
\mathcal{V}_{mn} &=
 a^{mn}a^{rs} a^{kt} \partial^2_{tr}a_{sk}
-  a^{ms}a^{nr} a^{kt} \partial^2_{tr}a_{sk}
-  a^{ms}a^{nr} a^{kt} \partial^2_{ts}a_{rk}
+  a^{ms}a^{nr} a^{kt} \partial^2_{tk}a_{rs}
\end{align}
Playing with the dummy indices, gives
\begin{align}
\mathcal{V}_{mn} &=
 \left(
   a^{mn}a^{rs} a^{kt} 
-  a^{mk}a^{nr} a^{st}
-  a^{mt}a^{ns} a^{kr} 
+  a^{ms}a^{nk} a^{rt} \right)\partial^2_{rt}a_{ks}
\end{align}
Does $\mathcal{V}_{mn}$ vanish ?!
And here I'm stuck, ...

Comment: What are $G$ and $a$ exactly ?

Comment: In this book, $G$ is the Einstein tensor and $a$ is the determinant of the matrix with the elements $a_{ij}$ of the covariant metric tensor

Comment: Just a few thoughts. The first term of the Einstein tensor is the [Ricci tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ricci_curvature#Introduction_and_local_definition). It is built from 2nd and 1st partial derivatives of the metric tensor. These are ordinary partial derivatives (not covariant $\nabla$ or $;$). It looks like a hard exercise. Probably best to read some other books also even if it is just to relax. One day wou will manage that.

Comment: Thx for the advice.

Comment: Just curious how you type those formulae quickly? Do you use mathtype style thing or just latex with snippets? I type formulae very slow... Thx

Comment: @Sherlock :  I just use plain Latex & I'm not that fast !